# How to use wt.exe from bash?

Tags: windows-terminal

When I run something like this under Bash/Ubuntu in Windows Terminal, it doesn't do anything:

```sh
wt.exe split-pane -p "Ubuntu 20.04"
```

How can I programatically split panes from bash?

Comment: This could be a bug in the terminal, I was not aware that the ability to programatically split panes in the terminal even existed. Are you sure this is something you can do?

Comment: Oooh, I see what you are saying now. It looks like you may need to add the -h or -v arguments to specify HOW the pane is supposed to open. You may want to run "wt" instead of "wt.exe" and the name of the profile that you have added could be the issue.

Comment: @ZachPedigo See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=linux it works from cmd.exe, but it opens a new Windows Terminal. I want to programatically split panes from *within* Windows Terminal, and within Bash (not just cmd.exe within Windows Terminal). The `.exe` extension is generally needed when you try to run Windows apps from bash.

Comment: There are keybindings that you can create in the settings.json file, but I am unsure of how you would even be able to run a command WITHIN Windows Terminal, I am unsure if this functionality is even available within bash.

Comment: Yep. I know about the hotkeys. I want to script the splitting though :-) I don't think bash needs to know anything about Windows Terminal. It can run wt.exe, but wt.exe needs to be programmed to send commands to the running instance, which it's looking like is not the case.

Comment: I highly doubt that wt.exe can be programmed to send commands to the current instance, at least if I am interpreting this correctly.

Comment: @ZachPedigo What do you mean? Why couldn't it? If you have vscode installed try running `code foo; code bar`. They both use the same window. Lots of apps do this. No reason wt can't. Hell, they even made vscode connect from bash to Windows. If anyone can do this, MS can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219682/discussion-between-zach-pedigo-and-mpen).